# shiftColumn method is not working when cell has formula

Tags: java, apache-poi

`sheet.shiftColumns(int start, int end, int shift)` is not working when the Excel sheet has formula. After this operation Excel is getting corrupted. It's working perfectly fine when the cell has no formula in it.

Any idea on this?

Code is something like this :

Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("sheetName");
sheet.shiftColumn(3,5,1); // this call corrupts the Excel sheet

The excel sheet im using to create the workbook has 5 columns in it and some cells have got formulae.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Please provide a [mcve] with observations and expectations. See [ask]

Comment: Hi, I have edited it. It was little tricky to explain because the API call itself was corrupting the Excel. However, I have received a perfect answer for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue only occurs using XSSF. If you open the `*.xlsx` after shifting columns and choose yes, so Excel tries repairing, you get told that formula records got removed from `/xl/calcChain.xml`-Part. So  `calcChain.xml` was not updated after shifting.

What is a `CalculationChain`? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/working-with-the-calculation-chain:

> The Calculation Chain part specifies the order in which cells in the
> workbook were last calculated. It only records information about cells
> containing formulas.

But after shifting cells having formulas, the `calcChain.xml` now contains cells not having formulas, explicitly the ones which were shifted to another place. So `calcChain.xml` needs to be updated. At least the cells which now not longer contain formulas needs to be removed.

Simplest workaround would be simply removing the whole `calcChain.xml`. This is possible since `Excel` uses calculation chain only for optimizing recalculation. It does not necessarily need the calculation chain but of course it fails the optimization process if there are wrong entries in calculation chain.

A method to remove all entries from `calcChain.xml` could look like this:

```
 private static void removeCalcChain(XSSFWorkbook workbook) throws Exception {
  CalculationChain calcchain = workbook.getCalculationChain();
  Method removeRelation = POIXMLDocumentPart.class.getDeclaredMethod("removeRelation", POIXMLDocumentPart.class); 
  removeRelation.setAccessible(true); 
  removeRelation.invoke(workbook, calcchain);
 }
```

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.CalculationChain;
import org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class ExcelShiftColums {
                
 private static void removeCalcChain(XSSFWorkbook workbook) throws Exception {
  CalculationChain calcchain = workbook.getCalculationChain();
  Method removeRelation = POIXMLDocumentPart.class.getDeclaredMethod("removeRelation", POIXMLDocumentPart.class); 
  removeRelation.setAccessible(true); 
  removeRelation.invoke(workbook, calcchain);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String inFilePath = "./ExcelExampleIn.xlsx";
  String outFilePath = "./ExcelExampleOut.xlsx";

  //String inFilePath = "./ExcelExampleIn.xls";
  //String outFilePath = "./ExcelExampleOut.xls";


  try (Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(inFilePath));
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFilePath ) ) {

   Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

   sheet.shiftColumns(3, 4, 1);
  
   if (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) removeCalcChain((XSSFWorkbook)workbook);

   workbook.write(out);
  }
 }
}
```

Why is this not an issue using `shiftRows`?

While new creating rows using `XSSFSheet.createRow` all the former cells in that row get removed using `XSSFRow.removeCell`. Using this `XSSFWorkbook.onDeleteFormula` gets called when former cell contains a formula. And this updates calculation chain too.

But `XSSFRow.createCell` does not removing the former cell but simply creates a new one in the place of the former one. So `XSSFWorkbook.onDeleteFormula` not gets called and calculation chain remains wrong.

That means one can simply make a corrupt `*.xlsx` having wrong calculation chain by doing:

```
...
XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(2);
row.createCell(2);
...
```

when `C3` was a cell containing a formula.

@Apache POI: Please patch `XSSFRow.createCell` so this also removes the former cells if there are such.

Comment: It worked! Great explanation ! Thank You Axel!

Comment: Hi, I found one more issue. shiftColumn is working with the work around you suggested for. xlsx files. However, it's not working for .xls files. Im getting another error,  File error: data may have been lost.